# Is there any adjective or phrase to describe two people with different approaches?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective or a phrase to describe two poets with different approaches to a particular subject:

Speaking of two (adjective) poets, it should be noted that ...

Can I use "theoretically different"? Any other possible choices?

Answer (score 1):

"Contrasting" would do it for me, but it wouldn't be specific to theory.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the two poets are **dichotomous.**

> He and his ragtag squad mates – who each fill their own war movie tropes – survive just about everything thrown at them all while getting barked at by their **dichotomous Sgt. Pierson and 1st Lt. Turner.**

[The Plainsman- 12th April 2017](http://www.theplainsman.com/article/2017/12/games-on-the-plains-cod-wwii-brings-back-the-basics)

> If something's **dichotomous**, it's divided into two distinct parts. It can describe a plant whose leaves pair off in opposing buds or anything — a government, a relationship — that has two divisions that are sharply opposed.

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dichotomous)